# Webpack: Module not found even though file is emitted

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

****Edit:** Basic setup repo [here](https://github.com/NickWoodward/clipboard-website)

Bit confused as to why webpack, or webpack-dev-server, can't seem to find a file it's emitting. Works fine with an older setup, but I tried to update to webpack 5 (amongst other things), and I've obviously made a mistake somewhere that I just can't spot. Would appreciate someone taking a look if you've time

Webpack output:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /bundle.js
assets by status 268 bytes [cached] 1 asset
assets by path *.js 281 KiB
  asset bundle.js 280 KiB [emitted] (name: index)
  asset index.f7be300873f5e9bf8004.hot-update.js 869 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: index)
asset index.html 4.9 KiB [emitted]
asset svg/spritesheet.svg 577 bytes [emitted]  // <-- This is the file I'm after
asset index.f7be300873f5e9bf8004.hot-update.json 29 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint index 281 KiB (268 bytes) = bundle.js 280 KiB index.f7be300873f5e9bf8004.hot-update.js 869 bytes 1 auxiliary asset
cached modules 172 KiB (javascript) 268 bytes (asset) [cached] 33 modules
runtime modules 27.4 KiB 13 modules
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 11.3 KiB [built]
```

The file I'm after is this one: `asset svg/spritesheet.svg 577 bytes [emitted]`

I'm importing it in my js file, and webpack obviously knows it's there because it's emitting the file, right?

But trying to reference it from my html results in

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg/spritesheet.svg'
```

The Html

```
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto text-center mb-40 px-10 pt-16">
      <!-- <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="" class="mx-auto my-16"> -->
      <svg class="mx-auto my-16"><use xlink:href="svg/spritesheet.svg#logo" /></svg>
    </div>
  </section>
```

My webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require("svg-sprite-loader/plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {index: "./src/index.ts"},
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          },
        port: 3000,
        open: {
            app: {
              name: 'chrome',
            },
          },
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchFiles: ["src/**/*"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
              },
              {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                        options: {
                            extract: true,
                            spriteFilename: 'svg/spritesheet.svg'
                        },
                    },
                    'svgo-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        // clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html',
            chunks: ['index'],
            // cache: false
        }),
        new SpriteLoaderPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Can anyone see what might be wrong?

**Edit: Not sure if this is relevant, but it now seems to be outputting 2 files - `svg/spritesheet.svg` and `[hash].svg` (line 4). Previous projects have never output separate files for each svg, just the spritesheet

```
asset bundle.js 280 KiB [emitted] (name: index)
asset index.html 5.01 KiB [emitted]
asset svg/spritesheet.svg 577 bytes [emitted]
asset da9c601f6125caa9dcb3.svg 268 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/images/logo.svg] (auxiliary name: index)
runtime modules 27.4 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 170 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 57.4 KiB 12 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.75 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.3 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.3 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.33 KiB 2 modules
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/ 13.8 KiB (javascript) 268 bytes (asset)
  modules by path ./src/*.css 13.7 KiB
    ./src/index.css 2.37 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 11.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/index.ts 124 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/images/logo.svg 42 bytes (javascript) 268 bytes (asset) [built] [code generated]
```

Comment: Can you set up a small repository with a minimal amount of configuration and code and push it to GitHub? That would help in narrowing down the issue.

Do you get the same issue with a regular build? If it's not there, maybe one way to handle this would be to skip extraction during development.

One more thing to do would be to try to find a comparable loader as svg-sprite-loader doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. Maybe you hit one of its bugs.

Comment: Hi Juho, I've added the repo - it's my basic config with TS and Tailwind. With my regular build I don't get this problem, but I can't really say that with any *real* confidence because I remember it being an absolute nightmare to set up the extract functionality last time too. But yeah, I've got the impression that this behaviour might be down to webpack5 and this loader not playing nicely. Have you any suggestions RE how to handle svg if not through this loader? I remember wanting to extract them as one spritesheet to reduce http calls, is the best practice now days just to inline them?

Comment: If the SVGs are tiny (say 20k or smaller) and there aren't too many per page, inlining should be fine. These days the [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) element supports `loading="lazy"` so technically one option would be even to leave them separate static assets and let the browser load on demand to reduce the initial payload.

Comment: It looks like the error isn't coming from the spritesheet loader. It's from html-webpack-plugin and specifically `xlink:href="svg/spritesheet.svg#logo"`. I think it's trying to resolve it from the filesystem before it actually exists. I'll dig a bit more info since I had the same problem in another context.

Comment: As a "fix", I replaced html-webpack-plugin with mine at https://github.com/NickWoodward/clipboard-website/pull/1 . I still don't understand why html-webpack-plugin tries to resolve the path, though. It's probably treating the path as an entry and likely it was a breaking change in their 5.0 which you can work around somehow. Maybe it's the `auto` change from https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#500-2021-02-03 .